# Display response values on div element in another page

Tags: jquery

How do I get value after ajax successful from patient_detail_search.php to display on my div element in patient_info.php?

Search js in patient_detail_search.php

```
    $('.search').on('click', function(){
        var search_by = $('.search_lists').val();
        var search_text = $('.search_text').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'patient_search.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {patient_search_by: search_by, patient_search_text: search_text},
            success:function(response){
                //... Get response value to display on patient_info.php
            }
        });
    });
```

Get response value from patient_detail_search.php to display on div element in patient_info.php

```
<div class="patient_detail_box">
    <!-- response value here -->
</div>
```

Comment: you can use jquery .html to put values in your div `$('.patient_detail_box').html(response)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the `.html()` function ([jQuery doc here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) or the `.text()` function ([jQuery doc here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)) to insert content into an element. In your case, you can try:

```
$('.search').on('click', function(){
    var search_by = $('.search_lists').val();
    var search_text = $('.search_text').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'patient_search.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {patient_search_by: search_by, patient_search_text: search_text},
        success:function(response){
            //... Send response value to class="patient_detail_box" on patient_info.php
            $('.patient_detail_box').html("Response from server: " + response);
        }
    });
});
```